Combine multiple rows into one row based on the repeating order of data attribute
I want to write an Oracle query to convert below table
Attribute       Value
product_id      P1
product_name            AAA
product_id      P2
product_name            BBB
product_id      P3
product_name            CCC

into below output:
product_id  product_name
P1          AAA
P2          BBB
P3          CCC

The attribute is always in the right order for each product because I convert them from a structure attribute-based XML data. for example:
<property name="product_id" value="P1" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_name" value="AAA" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_id" value="P2" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_name" value="BBB" valueType="string"/>

I appreciate your help.
I tried using PIVOT, but it expects aggregate function inside pivot operation, in my case, I don't have any column to apply the aggregate function.

Is there no column that can be used to determine which product ID goes with which product name? Relational databases should be considered unordered collections of rows.

It would be best if you fixed the XML conversion code to add a common ID that relates the rows.

@Barmar brings up a good point that product id and names should be grouped together. The following code makes that assumption, and that id/names are not unordered:
WITH RankedAttributes AS (
    SELECT 
        Value AS ProductValue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS rn,
        Attribute
    FROM your_table_name
),
GroupedAttributes AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'product_id' THEN ProductValue END) AS product_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'product_name' THEN ProductValue END) AS product_name
    FROM RankedAttributes
    GROUP BY (rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute ORDER BY rn))
)
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM GroupedAttributes
WHERE product_id IS NOT NULL;


Please provide an explanation of how your query works.

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to generate an increasing sequence for each row (per the assumption you stated in staging ground that the rows will be in order). Divide the generated row number by 2 (offset it by 1 first) to generate grouping. Use grouping to generate pivot table for your desired result.
WITH CTE(Attribute, Value, grouping) AS (
    SELECT p.*, TRUNC((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null)-1)/2) grouping FROM Product p
), PIVOT_TABLE(grouping, product_id, product_name) AS (
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(Value)
      FOR Attribute IN ('product_id', 'product_name')
    )
    ORDER BY grouping
)
SELECT product_id, product_name FROM PIVOT_TABLE

DB fiddle

Don't try to combine the rows, get pairs of rows when you parse the XML:
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/data/property[@name="product_id"]'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml)
         COLUMNS
           product_id   VARCHAR2(30) PATH './@value',
           product_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH './following-sibling::property[@name="product_name"][1]/@value'
       ) x

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml) AS
SELECT '<data>
<property name="product_id" value="P1" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_name" value="AAA" valueType="string"/>
<property name="product_id" value="P2" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_name" value="BBB" valueType="string"/>
<property name="product_id" value="P3" valueType="string"/> 
<property name="product_name" value="CCC" valueType="string"/>
</data>' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME




P1
AAA


P2
BBB


P3
CCC



fiddle
